# Windows software to easily enable/disable the Camera & Microphone

Tags: windows, security, camera, microphone

Background: Sometimes, I get kind of frightened when GlassWire tells me this with software **that should not be using a microphone**:

[image: Microphone usage alert]

So basically I'm looking for software that can allow me to easily disable any recording devices on my computer such as Cameras and Microphones. I would like the software to meet these requirements:

- Compatible with Windows 10
- Software is cheaper than $100
- Has a very minimal memory and CPU footprint (if it even runs in the background at all)
- Simple to operate (Best case scenario: it lists out all recording devices and allows me to enable/disable each one on a case by case basis.)